# How to generate a linerange plot with a dodged position of grouped lines using plot_ly()

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to try to generate a similar plot like this using plot_ly (instead of directly using ggplotly)

[image: by ggplot]

### ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
# using ggplot2 can get the results

df <- data.frame(
  trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
  lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(trt, resp, colour = group))
p + geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
```

### plotly

For plotly, the most similar I can get is like this. Is there a way to dodge the lines?

Thank you!

[image: by plotly]

```
# using plot_ly

library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
  lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)

df1 <- df %>% pivot_longer(names_to = "po", cols = c("resp", "upper", "lower"))
df1 %>% group_by(trt) %>% plot_ly( x = ~trt, y = ~value, color = ~group) %>% add_trace(type = "scatter", mode = "markers+lines")
```